# Show alert on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I'm sure this will turn out to be very simple, I got a piece of code that doesn't seem to be loading properly. This is the code I have on my Simple php page

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function exit_alert(){
        alert("Go Install the XX Antivirus now\n\nto prevent more issues!");
    }
</script>
```

The user clicks the only button on the page, as soon as he does it, an exit alert should pop with a message like "Go Install the XX Antivirus now to prevent more issues". The exit alert should be a message only, and should only have an OK button on the bottom, and not ask the user Stay or leave.

I've tried  lot of stuff but nothing seems to be working, I could really use your help :)

Big thanks in Advance!

Comment: So, what *does* happen when you hook a button to that function?

Comment: The stay or leave buttons are proprietary to the browser, meaning that you can't change it because it depends on which browser the client is using. Are you trying to prevent the user from leaving the page? That's pretty annoying for any website.

Comment: That's interesting, I gotta do more research on it. I don't care if it's annoying, it means extra 30% return on investment.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can opt to not load an entire Javascript library for something as simple as this:

```
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('onclick', exit_alert);
```

Comment: Missing a `.`  after `('#button')` ;)

Comment: @DaveSalomon Shhhhhhh. >.> (fixed)

Comment: Interesting how would I implement this code on my page?

Comment: @MikeWhite Simply add an ID to the button (and make sure it corresponds to the ID in the query selector. "#BUTTON_ID")
You can add this in a script tag on your page, and voila.

Comment: I'm not used to this type of coding at all, I really appreciate your answer but I was just wondering if you guys knew what was missing on the code above that's causing it not work?

Comment: @MikeWhite Well...just having the function is fine, but it won't do anything unless it's told to do so. Two ways you can go about this are adding an onclick attribute to the button OR...by telling javascript to do it. Just having the exit_alert() function does nothing, however. It must be called.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with jQuery

```
$( "#targetId" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Comment: Thank you, how would I implement this code on my page?

Comment: @MikeWhite you would put the id for the button where #targetId is.  You should also make sure to include jQuery in your imports.

Comment: I'm not used to this type of coding at all, I really appreciate your answer but I was just wondering if you guys knew what was missing on the code above that's causing it not work?